# Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, parsing, text-parsing

I am facing a problem with what R calls connection, when I am web-parsing house-related data, such as house area, house region, pricing. But the website is originally in Russian language only, so when the parsing `rvest` package extracts the texts with Russian characters, it produces this sort of an error `<U+0433>`. It changes to Unicode text instead. Here take a look:

```
values
# [1] "from agent"     "panel, 1997 г." "10"             "255 sq. m"      "central" 

str(values)
# chr [1:5] "from agent" "panel, 1997 <U+0433>." "10" "255 sq. m" "central"

# Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection
# Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection
# Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection
```

As you see, the symbol `г` converted into `<U+0433>`. It starts producing connection error.

[image]

What should I do to fix it? So, it can parse both Latin and Russian characters naturally.

Comment: The Unicode symbols you are getting here _are_ the correct characters. It is just that the font used in your R console does not have these symbols, so this is how they are displayed.

Comment: What can I do to make R console read them and interpret them correctly? ...

Comment: It _is_ interpreting them correctly, just not _diplaying_ them as you would like. Perhaps changing the default font in RStudio to one that you know handles Cyrillic characters?